# Deadlock on communication buffer: SQL Server 2008 R2 running stored procedures for data warehouse

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, deadlock

Currently running SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 on 64-Bit Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise on a Intel dual 8-core processor server with 128 GB RAM and 1TB internal SCSI drive.

Server has been running our Data Warehouse and Analysis Services packages since 2011.  This server and SQL instance is not used for OLTP.

Suddenly and without warning, all of the jobs that call SSIS packages that build the data warehouse tables (using Stored Procedures) are failing with "Deadlock on communication buffer" errors.  The SP that generates the error within the package is different each time the process is run.

However, the jobs will run fine if SQL Server Profiler is running to trace at the time that the jobs are initiated.

This initially occured on our Development server (same configuration) in June.  Contact with Microsoft identified Disk I/O issues, and suggested setting MaxDOP = 8, which has mitigated the deadlock issue, but introduced an issue where the processes can take up to 3 times longer at random intervals.

This just occurred today on our Production server.  MaxDOP is currently set to zero.  There have been no changes to OS, SQL Server or the SSIS packages in the past month.  The jobs ran fine overnight on September 5th, but failed with the errors overnight last night (September 6th) and continue to fail on any retry.

The length of time that any one job will run before failing is not consisent nor is there consistency between jobs.  Jobs that take 2 minutes to run to completion previously will fail in seconds, where jobs that normally take 2 hours may run anywhere from 30 - 90 minutes before failing.

Comment: `failed with the errors overnight last night` - can you post the error messages ? Also, did you check the if your schedulers are not overloaded with work being queued due to large transactions or long running queries or blocking ? MaxDop is 0 = meaning it will use all available threads which might lead to thread starvation. Also, check the wait stats on the server that might point you in right direction.

Comment: Have you noticed any increase in the amount of time that the server is taking to run these jobs?

Comment: Voting to migrate to DBA.SE so we can enlist the wicked smart folks

Comment: Also is there a possiblity of increased traffic on this machine?

Comment: Have you captured any deadlock graphs?  You may want to enable it in your [error log](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/252/tracing-a-sql-server-deadlock/).

Comment: `Deadlock on communication buffer` is typically (read always AFAIK) bug territory. The usual mitigation is to lower `MAXDOP` until it stops occurring while simultaneously trying to get your Microsoft support call past first line and on to someone that is interested in fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered changing the isoloation level of the database. This can help when parallel reads and writes are happening on the database.